# How to send attachments and embeds in the same message?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

How to send attachments and embeds in the same message?

To send attachments:

```
if (message.content === ';file') {
  const attachment = new Attachment('https://i.imgur.com/FpPLFbT.png');
  message.channel.send(`text`, attachment);
}
```

To send embeds:

```
if (msg.content === ';name') {
  const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
    .setTitle(`About`)
    .setDescription(`My name is <@${msg.author.id}>`)
    .setColor('RANDOM');
  msg.channel.send(embed);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

To understand how to accomplish your task, you first need to know how the `TextBasedChannel.send()` method works. Let's take a look at [`TextChannel.send()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=send) from the docs.

> **`.send([content], [options])`**
>
> **`content`** *([StringResolvable](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/StringResolvable))*: Text for the message.
>   **`options`** *([MessageOptions](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/MessageOptions) or [Attachment](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Attachment) or [RichEmbed](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/RichEmbed))*: Options for the message, can also be just a RichEmbed or Attachment

Now, let's see how your usage applies.

---

> ```js
> message.channel.send(`text`, attachment);
> ```

In this case, `` `text` `` is serving as the `content` parameter of the method, and `attachment` is passed as the `options` parameter.

> ```js
> msg.channel.send(embed);
> ```

Here, the `content` parameter is omitted, and `embed` is passed as the `options` parameter.

---

While keeping your same style of code, you can utilize an object to hold *both* the embed and attachment for the `options` parameter.

```js
// const { Attachment, RichEmbed } = require('discord.js');

const attachment = new Attachment('https://puu.sh/DTwNj/a3f2281a71.gif', 'test.gif');

const embed = new RichEmbed()
  .setTitle('**Test**')
  .setImage('attachment://test.gif') // Remove this line to show the attachment separately.

message.channel.send({ embed, files: [attachment] })
  .catch(console.error);
```

Comment: Thankyou so much the information... :)
It's working now :)))

Appreciate your hard work...

Answer (score 1):

The [`TextChannel.send`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=send) function can take different [options](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/MessageOptions).

So you can just do this:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on('message', (msg) => {
  msg.channel.send({
    embed:  new Discord.RichEmbed()
      .setTitle('A slick little embed')
      .setColor(0xFF0000)
      .setDescription('Hello, this is a slick embed!'),
    files: [{
      attachment: './README.md',
      name: 'readme'
    }]
  })
    .then(console.log)
    .catch(console.error);
});
```

However, if you want to add an image in your embed, just follow the example in the [guide](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/embeds.html#embed-preview) or this example given in the api doc:

```js
// Send an embed with a local image inside
channel.send('This is an embed', {
  embed: {
    thumbnail: {
         url: 'attachment://file.jpg'
      }
   },
   files: [{
      attachment: 'entire/path/to/file.jpg',
      name: 'file.jpg'
   }]
})
  .then(console.log)
  .catch(console.error);
```

Comment: this is also working.. thank you for your efforts :)

Comment: @DhirajSinghKarki don't hesitate to accept slothiful answer as it was more detailed than mine. This way people looking for an answer will know that the solution is working